# Encryption or Hashing of Date Value

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography

I have an old program that has been discontinued which communicates with an SQL database.  When I enter certain information in the defunct software, it is encrypted, encoded, or hashed before being entered into the database.

I am creating another application to interact with the same data, and I need to figure out how the end result is being produced.

Here's an example:

```
I enter 6/18/2017,  I get y/7w/iXIE

I enter 6/18/2099,  I get y/7w/iXBM

I enter 6/12/2017,  I get y/7c/iXIE

I enter 12/11/2018, I get SN/u0/ZmWk
```

The last one throws me for a loop... what method is being used and how can I replicate this?

---

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/), [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It might be format preserving encryption or just substatutions. In all cases the number of characgters in each section delimited by / are the same number of characters. With enough samples, all 12 months, 31 days and years you should be able to match the method.

```
6/18/2017
y/7w/iXIE

6/18/2099
y/7w/iXBM

6/12/2017
y/7c/iXIE

12/11/2018
SN/u0/ZmWk
```

```
months:    6 -> y,      12 -> SN  
days:     11 -> u0,     12 -> 7c,     18 -> 7w  
years:  2017 -> iXIE, 2018 -> ZmWk, 2099 -> iXBM
```

Comment: Thanks!  So, if I get all the samples...  All the days, all the months, and a number of years...  How would I go about figuring out the method?

Comment: Given a date just substitute the values.